# Any open public data sets for the English Premier League (EPL)?

Tags: data-request, sports

The new 2014/15 season kicks off on Aug/16. Wondering what's the state of open data for the English Premier League. Any open data sets available (incl. teams, players, squads, stadiums, old seasons, goals and match stats, and so on)?

Ideally the data set is in an open plain text format such as CSV (comma-separated values), JSON (javascript objects), SQL (structured query language), etc. and in the public domain (no rights reserved, no copyright) or using a permissive license (only attribution required, for example).

Any insight appreciated.

Disclosure:  I'm the project lead of the football.db project (includes a match schedule for the 2014/15 season; added by hand - play by play, for example) e.g.

- [`openfootball/en-england`](https://github.com/openfootball/en-england) - football.db  Datasets for English Premier League
- [`footballcsv/en-england`](https://github.com/footballcsv/en-england) - football.csv Datasets for English Premier League

Answer (score 15):

There is a list of soccer datasets and APIs [here](http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2014/03/08/guide-to-football-and-soccer-data-and-apis/) from [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14256826/1402368). Hope that helps.

EDIT: Quoted text from the article linked above, as requested:

> [openfootball](http://openfootball.github.io/) has started a free (open source) public domain football
>   database. The data is historical data, meaning no lives scores but the
>   data does include the schedule, teams and players for the upcoming
>   2014 World Cup along with global league data. This is a very promising
>   project and has the potential to be the definitive source for
>   historical data for the public. The data is stored in various repos on
>   github. Start browsing and contributing at [github.com/openfootball](https://github.com/openfootball/).
>   See the [opensport Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/opensport) for discussion and questions.
>
> [footballsquads.co.uk](http://www.footballsquads.co.uk/) has current and historical squad details for
>   clubs and national teams from all across the world for many leagues
>   and competitions, including the 2014 World Cup squads.
>
> [Rec.Sport.Soccer Statistics Foundation (RSSSF)](http://www.rsssf.com/) has massive collection
>   of formatted plain text statistics. An [example of English Premier
>   leagues results](http://www.rsssf.com/tablese/eng2014.html#premier).
>
> [ESPN API](http://developer.espn.com/docs) has an API for registered users (free). You can get a list of
>   all the players in the EPL. However they are very limited in their
>   data. They restrict all fixtures and scores to “strategic partners.”
>   However, you can get lists of players and teams.
>
> [opta Playground](http://www.optasports.com/playground-section.aspx) has a developer program that provides very limited
>   access to historical data. The site reads “Opta can provide data for
>   programmers wishing to develop a mobile app or website with selected
>   historical data available to download.” You have to request permission
>   in an email. I applied and they sent me the xml data set for 10 rounds
>   of games from the start of the 2007/2008 Bundesliga 2. The more
>   detailed game data had either x,y coordinates of game events. A very
>   impressive dataset but it felt more like an advertisement. The data
>   provided I had no interest in and I’m not sure why an indie developer
>   would spend time working on a data set they could never afford.
>
> [StatsFC](https://statsfc.com/) used to have an restful JSON API of all EPL scores and
>   fixtures. It was about $8 us dollars a month but was recently shut
>   down. There is no doubt it was related to data rights. See their
>   [official statement](https://statsfc.com/statements).
>
> [CrowdScores beta](https://crowdscores.com/) is UK company trying to crowd-source the football
>   data collection process. You sign up for an account and report game
>   events to their servers. They have web/iphone/android interfaces for
>   reporting. They reward the top reporter with a season ticket. They
>   data collection process is ideal but they might have to work on the
>   incentives. I believe a better incentive would be to allow the
>   reporters who contribute access to an API of all the data collected.
>
> [openfooty API](http://www.footytube.com/openfooty/) had promising API documentation but a quick look at the
>   developer forums shows a stale community and questions about why no
>   one seems to actually be able to get a developer key.
>
> [football-data.co.uk](http://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php) has made a lot of historical league data available
>   as csv files. The data includes results and a lot of betting/odds
>   related data. I have tried to aggregate and clean up the data in the
>   following repo [github.com/jokecamp/FootballData](https://github.com/jokecamp/FootballData)
>
> [www.european-football-statistics.co.uk](http://www.european-football-statistics.co.uk/) is a visually dated website but
>   has a lot of historical football data (mostly an overview of
>   league/tournament results) displayed in nice clean HTML tables. Looks
>   like they already have 2014 EPL stats.
>
> [openligadb.db](http://www.openligadb.de/Webservices/Sportsdata.asmx) has an old-school windows asmx web service with methods
>   such as “GetGoalsByMatch()”
>
> [Linked Soccer Data](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1026/paper6.pdf) is a white paper on one group’s attempt to “create
>   a dataset including reliable information about soccer events covering
>   as many historical data as available including recent competition
>   results.” Some dead links but worthwhile to skim.

Comment: Thanks. Great list by Joe Kampschmidt. Can you edit your answer and add all the English Premier League parts as quotes or summary to your answer if possible? Cheers.