# Seeking the attendance data for English football teams for all four tiers

Tags: data-request, sports, football

I am trying to analyse the attendance and position relationship of football clubs in the 4 tiers (Premier League, Championship, League 1 and League 2). Unfortunately, I am not able to get a legitimate source for the attendance data for each year since 2005/2006 season.

I already have reviewed the following question posted:

[Any open public data sets for the English Premier League (EPL)?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3369/any-open-public-data-sets-for-the-english-premier-league-epl)

Also went through the Kaggle database:
https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer

All these sources focuse on the scores and wins, but no attendance records for any year for any tier.

Can anyone guide me to obtain this data set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find attendance data since the season 1889 (and since 1922 for all top four tiers) from [European Football Statistics](http://www.european-football-statistics.co.uk/attn.htm)

Comment: Thank you so much! Do have any information for the source that they use to collect this data?